# Помогите расставить знаки препинания (3)

Tags: пунктуация

Но нужно учиться принимать перемены и переставать их бояться ведь они неизбежны

Comment: Может быть отбросите страх и начнёте расставлять?

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова, Если Вы не против, предлагаю соблюдать конвенцию (см на Мете): первый раз — название без индекса, второй раз — с индексом (2) и т. д.

Comment: Конечно-конечно, как же я могу быть против? Просто я подумала, что если нет предложения с "единичкой", то я вполне могу ее поставить. По принципу: Заголовок; Заголовок (1); Заголовок (2)... Только не пойму никак, почему же нужно пропускать цифирку "1"?

Comment: Обычно единицу не ставят: "Матрица", "Матрица 2", "Матрица 3"... Первым (Матрица 1) считается тот, что без номера.

Comment: 1. Сдаюсь! - Ваша "Матрица" меня убедила. 2. Я дополнила свой ответ доп. ссылкой.

Answer (score 1):

Но нужно учиться принимать перемены и перестать их бояться – **ведь они неизбежны.**

Это бессоюзное сложное предложение, вторая часть **в данном случае** имеет значение причины. По классическим правилам ставится двоеточие, но оно часто заменяется тире.

В этом случае не делается  увеличенная предупредительная пауза, второе предложение имеет присоединительный характер.

**Примечание.** Лучше изменить вид глагола: перестать, а не переставать.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

1) ***ВЕДЬ*** в книгах по грамматике определяется как **союз-частица**, стиль разговорный.

2) Это скорее **структурный элемент, определяющий отношения в БСП**, чем союз с определенным значением в  СПП.

3) Слово ***ВЕДЬ*** соотносится с глаголом ***ведать, знать***, поэтому может иметь разные смысловые оттенки: причины, условия, и всё это с дополнительным значением присоединения или распространения предыдущего высказывания. Точно такую функцию выполняют наречия и частицы в БСП, уточняя отношения между двумя частями предложения.

4) А еще ***ВЕДЬ*** образует союзные соединения вида ***А ВЕДЬ, НО ВЕДЬ***, причем в этом случае роль у него вспомогательная.

5) Также обратим внимание **на постановку знаков препинания** в предложении со словом ***ВЕДЬ*** – это двоеточие, тире, запятая, но при этом выбор зависит **от структуры предложения** (как и в БСП, но не в СПП).

**И вывод:** союз-частицу ***ВЕДЬ*** вряд ли можно считать самостоятельным союзом со значением причины в СПП.

**Примеры:**

Тут уж римляне не выдержали: ***ведь*** апостол Павел учил их совсем другому.

Никакого решения по открытому письму пленум не принимал, ***ведь*** этот вопрос не значился в повестке.

Потребовалось немало времени, чтобы не просто понять, что такое искусство политика, **а ведь** депутат ― политик, прежде всего.

У нас, конечно, тоже нервишки порой пошаливают, но всё-таки большого давления не испытываем ― **ведь** на золото не претендуем.

Боже, как же вы жили ― ***ведь*** в Советском Союзе не было совсем дорогого белья!

Answer (score 1):

[Грамота](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_185) указывает, что между частями **бессоюзного** предложения ставится двоеточие, если вторая часть указывает на причину того, что описано в первой части (в предложение можно вставить союз ПОТОМУ ЧТО).

Однако наше предложение не является бессоюзным: слово *ведь* выступает в нем в качестве **союза**, который "присоединяет предложения, содержащие указание на причину, обоснование предыдущего высказывания" ([Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8C)). Пример из словаря — *Пора домой, ведь уже поздно* — содержит запятую, что обычно для СПП.

Таким образом, стандартный вариант — постановка запятой, а тире можно считать допустимым авторским знаком. А вот постановку двоеточия трудно оправдать.

Однако надо отметить, что в Нацкорпусе все три варианта (запятая, тире, двоеточие перед *ведь*) представлены тысячами вхождений. Очевидно, тот, кто ставит двоеточие, рассуждает иначе, чем я.

А в данном конкретном примере, на мой взгляд, можно поставить запятую, но я бы предпочел тире, чтобы обозначить паузу и тем самым подчеркнуть вторую часть.

**Но нужно учиться принимать перемены и перестать их бояться – ведь они неизбежны.**

Дополнение. *Переставать* заменено на *перестать*. В данном предложении *учиться* относится только к *принимать перемены*. Для уточнения смысла можно изменить порядок изложения: *Но нужно перестать бояться перемен и **научиться** их принимать – ведь они неизбежны.*

Comment: В этом предложении явно присутствует пауза, которую нужно обозначить двоеточием или тире. Это связано с разной структурой частей предложения и подчеркнутым значением причины (для этого варианта). Но запятая не сможет обозначить эти отношения. Она ставится, когда вторая часть достаточно распространена или сравнима по объему с первой частью, чтобы выразить необходимое  обоснование.

Answer (score 1):

[**ведь**](http://old-punctum.ru/punctum.php?sid=263), *союз и частица*

1. Союз. Синтаксические конструкции, присоединяемые союзом "ведь", выделяются (или отделяются) запятыми.
   Союз присоединяет предложения, содержащие указание на причину, обоснование предыдущего высказывания:
   *Полагаемся на тебя, ты ведь один знаешь дорогу. Пора домой, ведь уже поздно.*

[**переставать**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/212267/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)
1. Прекращать какое-либо действие, выходить из какого-либо состояния (обычно в сочетании с неопределённой формой глагола).
Смысл: *но нужно прекращать бояться...*

[**перестать**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/es/126434)
Прекратить какое-либо действие, занятие, выйти из какого-либо состояния и т. п.
Перестать петь.
Смысл: ***но нужно прекратить бояться...*** (Лучше использовать глагол этого вида.)

**Но нужно учиться принимать перемены и перестать их бояться, ведь они неизбежны.** 
(В конце предложения необходима точка.)

Или без союза "ведь" (вот тогда, думаю, необходимо тире):
**Но нужно учиться принимать перемены и перестать их бояться — они неизбежны.**

Вот некоторые похожие примеры:

*Но в целом, я пришла к тому, что не нужно бояться допускать ошибки, ведь они неизбежны.*

*Ошибки случаются и в таких отношениях, ведь они неизбежны.*
[**Н. Родионова, И. Удилова. Секреты счастливых отношений**](https://books.google.ee/books?id=Ql4kDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT12&lpg=PT12&dq=%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85,%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8C%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B.&source=bl&ots=Aq4-PQ79lV&sig=9ZXJXF9xgfIrZ4xl3aP_SLZ0N8Y&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjB7MbFg-XaAhXFYlAKHQcxCAIQ6AEwAXoECAAQMA#v=onepage&q=%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%20%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85%2C%20%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8C%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B.&f=false)

Comment: А примеры откуда. Источник заслуживает доверия?

Comment: В первую очередь, конечно, я ориентировалась на правило  и только потом искала подходящие примеры.